# Downloadable data resources / content for iphone / ipod applications

Tags: iphone, bundles

I am working on an application that uses quite a large amount of content (images and text). I would like to be able to provide additional content bundles to those - and only to those - who already have my app on their device. E.g., if my app were a newspaper / magazine / book reader, I want to give the subscribers the ability to download new issues / books (along with the ability to select, at any time, any of the already downloaded bundles at will). So the app will work with only one bundle at a time - but the users should be able to select any bundle.

As I mentioned, I only want to provide the extra bundles to those who already have my app on their device, and I wonder if it is possible to provide these extras via AppStore.

I understand I could always get extra content downloaded by my app from a website and installed locally, but in such situation I could not control who will be accessing my website (and it is always possible to discover its URL, along with any "unique" identifiers, via traffic sniffing).
I am sure there is some standard solution used by some or other  newspaper / magazine / book reader applications, but I cannot find any documentation / api / code examples.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [StoreKit](http://developer.apple.com/iPhone/library/navigation/Frameworks/CoreServices/StoreKit/index.html), it sounds like exactly what you need.